# Selenium Java: How to get current ChromeDriver instance's user directory and version using ChromeCapabilities

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to know the following information from my current running ChromeDriver:

exact temporary user-data folder that ChromeDriver created by default

the driver version

According to [this](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities) page, It should be part of the ChromeDriver's returned capabilities:[image]

**What I tried so far:**

```
Capabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
System.out.println(caps.getCapability("userDataDir"));
System.out.println(caps.getCapability("chrome.chromedriverVersion"));
```

Both are giving me null. I do know that I'm not manually setting the ChromeOptions "--user-data-dir" but still, I know that ChromeDriver will use a certain directory by default.

Same goes with the version, It makes sense that we can retrieve the current driver's version at will right?

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE 1:**
I'm calling the code above right before passing the `caps` instance as a parameter to the ChromeDriver constructor.

Here's a slightly more insightful snippet:

```
public class Driver implements WebDriver {

   private WebDriver webDriver;
   private Capabilities caps;

   public Driver(){
      caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
      caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
      caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_APPLICATION_CACHE, true);
      caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_ALERTS, true);
      caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_FINDING_BY_CSS, true);

      //Am I not doing this correctly?
      System.out.println(caps.getCapability("userDataDir"));
      System.out.println(caps.getCapability("chrome.chromedriverVersion"));

      webDriver = new ChromeDriver(caps);
   }
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**
Regarding the version number, I realized that whenever I do

```
Capabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
```

the DesiredCapabilities class is passing a blank string as a parameter to the version number.

[image]
[image]

With that said, is there any way I can get the current chrome driver version (boxed below)? I know this information is stored somewhere but I do not know how to get it.

[image]

As for the temporary user-data folder, I still have no idea how to get it even after watching the capabilities and the webdriver object created.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Can you consider updating us exactly at which point are you trying to read the capabilities? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB I have updated my question with a slightly more insightful snippet. Hope my update helps..TIA!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @MikeJRamsey56's casting tip, I managed to figure this out.

Here's a dirty (but) working solution. Hope this can help others out.

```
public class Driver implements WebDriver {

   private WebDriver webDriver;
   private Capabilities caps;

   public Driver(){
      System.setProperty(ChromeDriverService.CHROME_DRIVER_EXE_PROPERTY, "the/driver/path/chromedriver.exe");
      caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
      webDriver = new ChromeDriver(caps);

      //Cast webDriver instance to RemoteWebDriver
      caps = ((RemoteWebDriver) webDriver).getCapabilities();

      //Call getCapability and cast to Map. 
      //This line will give a Type Safety warning, hence the "dirty" in my solution.
      Map<String, String> a = (Map<String, String>) caps.getCapability("chrome");
      System.out.println(String.format("Driver Version: %s", a.get("chromedriverVersion")));
      System.out.println(String.format("Temp dir: %s", a.get("userDataDir")));
   }
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

My initialization logic looks like this:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = null;
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", user_dir + "/src/main/resources/drivers/ChromeDriver/chromedriver");

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
options.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
prefs.put("excludeSwitches", "enable-automation");
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability("version", "latest");
capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "chrome");
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

try {
    webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("**>uh-oh " + e.getMessage());
}

webDriver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
Capabilities cap = ((RemoteWebDriver) webDriver).getCapabilities();
String browserName = cap.getBrowserName();
String browserVersion = cap.getVersion();
System.out.println("Browser name=" + browserName + ", version=" + browserVersion);
```

Comment: When you do `capabilities.setCapability("version", "latest");`, will `cap.getVersion();` give you `"latest"` or the boxed number on my question (UPDATE 2)?

Comment: Gives the actual version of the Chrome browser.  The key is to cast to class RemoteWebDriver.

Comment: Sorry but this is not the answer I am looking for. Although the casting tip helped me figure it out so I'll upvote this at least. Thanks a bunch!